# detect keystrokes in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext and a button. I want the button onclick handler to be called when enter/carriage return is pressed on keyboard while in edittext.

xml layout:

```
   <EditText android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:maxLength="1"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enter" />

    <Button 
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="handler"/>
```

handler looks like this:

```
public void handler(View view){
//handles buttonclick here    
    }
```

I have read other answers on Stack overflow, but none of the solutions are working for me because probably I am doing something wrong. Can someone tell me with code how to call handler when ENTER key is pressed in edittext?

The device I'm running the code on is an Acer Iconia A501Tablet with Honeycomb.

Here's the complete java file
http://pastebin.com/tbTTu7T7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

      switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
          button.performClick();
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
      }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            /// call click event here by passing view
            //or u can write code which u want to be called onclick
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as kettu's answer and it isn't working. enter is not getting detected. I don't know if it's relevant, but the device I'm running the code on is an Acer Iconia A501Tablet with Honeycomb

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
       button.performClick();
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This isn't working.. No response on hitting enter. also, note that the edittext is set to android:maxLength="1".. could this be the reason why the enter key isnt getting detected?

Comment: maxLength is not causing a problem.. doesn't work without it as well.

Comment: just try using  android:imeOptions="" in xml. more details at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html